# transform each word of a cell into a new row

Tags: python, pandas

Im trying to split every word into a new row for the dataframe above, i tryed to search and try a lot but i have no clue to what to do yet. Somebody know how to do it? Thanks!!!

input

```
+------+------------------------+
| User |         Answer         |
+------+------------------------+
| a    | The trainning was good |
| b    | Could be better        |
+------+------------------------+
```

desired output

```
+------+-----------+
| User |  Answer   |
+------+-----------+
| a    | The       |
| a    | trainning |
| a    | was       |
| a    | good      |
| b    | Could     |
| b    | be        |
| b    | better    |
+------+-----------+
```

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with NLTK (or stemming), please be careful not to add tags that aren't relevant to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with `split`, then explode the column:

```
(df.assign(Answer=df['Answer'].str.split())
   .explode('Answer')
   .reset_index(drop=True))

  User    Answer
0    a       The
1    a  training
2    a       was
3    a      good
4    b     Could
5    b        be
6    b    better
```

Where,

```
df['Answer'].str.split()

0    [The, training, was, good]
1           [Could, be, better]
Name: Answer, dtype: object

_.explode()

0         The
0    training
0         was
0        good
1       Could
1          be
1      better
Name: Answer, dtype: object
```

Is responsible for converting the sentence into a list of words, then flattening them across multiple rows.